# GUI simulation only shows end result

Tags: user-interface, 2d, simulation, simulator

I've got a Simulation built and need to add a GUI onto it to choose x amounts of steps to simulate. The program right now only shows me the end result and I need it to show the simulation.

I can see in the command window its running, but just wont show movement of characters.

The simulation is a 2d grid of a room and people moving around based on who they are next and how happy they would be. Without the GUI the program works fine so I assumed if putting the code from the main arg in the non GUI code into the action performed for my simulate button it would work.

Right now this is the actionPerformed method:

```
private void simButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Simulator simulator = new Simulator(50, 50, 43);

        // simulate the project for 10 rounds
        simulator.simulate(10);  
        // simulator.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you don't update the graphics anywhere from within the simulation itself, but since all you've shown us is `simulator.simulate(10)` there's no way for us to actually know what's going on.

Comment: Sorry new to java what is it extra that you would need to see? the whole simulation code is huge

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're asking a debugging question:  "Why doesn't my code...?"  Bear in mind that people can't debug code they can't see.  Have you tried stepping through your program with a debugger to find out why you're not getting what you expect?